# How to check if any java jar file is running in the background in Windows?

Tags: java, windows

I've used **javaw** to running an application in the background. And it starts at windows startup.

To Achieve I've used following command in a startup-> .bat file

```
javaw -Xmx200m -jar C:\DataLoggingApplication\application.jar
```

Since it runs in the background, I'm not able see to if an application already is running. I'm using windows operating system.

How to achieve this?

Comment: @specializt updated

Answer (score 1):

In windows, you can find a process by its name like this:

```
tasklist | FIND "applicationName"
```

Answer (score 0):

Hope this will help you out:

```
wmic process where "name like '%application.jar%'" get processid,commandline
```

or

```
wmic process where "name like '%jar%'" get processid,commandline
```

or

```
wmic process where "name like '%java%'" get processid,commandline
```

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve that using *Windows Powershell* by executing this to get the command that was invoked to run the java app and the process id:

```
String command = "powershell.exe  Get-WmiObject win32_process -Filter \"name='javaw.exe' and commandline like '%filename.jar%'\"|select Pid,CommandLine"
```

Answer (score -1):

You can use the `jvisualvm` which is within the jdk: `%JAVA_HOME%/bin/jvisualvm`.

Comment: its an oracle-specific tool, users of any OpenJDK do not have it.